# Launcher app icon on Amazon TV Stick

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-resources, amazon-fire-tv, app-launcher

App launcher icon is wrongly displayed on Amazon TV Stick device on home scren.
Image is correctly displayed in category Recent but in category Apps&Games instead to be rectangular it is shrinked to square as shown in image:
https://ibb.co/bYGiym

I have Amazon TV Stick with FireOS 5.2.6.1.
For testing I am using android app just with empty activity, and in drawable directory placed image 1280x720px, as they specified in https://developer.amazon.com/docs/app-submission/asset-guidelines.html#firetvassets

1. I read that there might be different behavior with apps in development and those that are uploaded to the Appstore. Is this correct?
2. Are resources actually loaded from some Amazon web service rather than referenced from the manifest file and
3. is it possible that this icon will be correctly shown only after submitting it to the Appstore?
4. Why FireOS shrinks app icon on home screen to square or4:3 format?
5. So, is this some problem with Amazon and FireOS and installing applications localy or I am just not setting up things correctly? 
   If it is up to me what should I do localy in my environment in order that icon
   is displayed in correct rectangular shape in all categories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, Fire TV and Fire Stick will pull from your mobile icons when you side-load a build. You won't see the actual TV app icon until the app is available after submission.

I haven't tried it, but there could be workarounds, like maybe replacing the square mobile icons with the rectangular TV app icons, but it sounds to me like you've already done something similar, and it's forcing it to be square. If that workaround works, I'm not sure it's worth the risk of forgetting to change it back to a square.

Comment: And yes, I realize this was from January and you probably have your answer by now. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and sorry for delayed response :)
Yes, I can confirm that after submission app icon is shown correctly. And also I tried just for testing purposes and had successful results when I generated vector asset  from android studio for app icon.

Comment: @zwex Hey I know its been a couple of years, but I was wondering if you could share how you added an vector icon for the app?

Comment: i remember when submitting Fire TV app it also ask additional icon 1280x720, is it the one that will be used for the Home screen in Fire TV device? or is it something else?